# How can I call a batch file(.bat) in c#?

Tags: c#, batch-file

How can I call a batch file(.bat) in c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Execute Commands From C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/dllsandexecutables/article.php/c14441)

```
public static int ExecuteCommand(string Command, int Timeout)
{
    int exitCode;
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + Command);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    process.WaitForExit(Timeout);
    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    process.Close();
    return exitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Process.Start("cmd.exe", pathToBat);`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx):

```
Process.Start("path to batch file");
```