# How can I force a .bat file to be launched and run using a .Net command prompt

Tags: .net, batch-file, command-prompt

If you double click on a .bat file, windows will run it in a command prompt.

I want a specific .bat file to be launched using the .Net command prompt as it uses gacutil.

How can I achieve this?

thanks!

Comment: Any reason you can't use the full path to `gacutil`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a batch file(.bat) in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996777/how-can-i-call-a-batch-file-bat-in-c)

Comment: Not a duplicate. He isn't asking how to launch a batch file from C#. He wants to have the environment variables from the VS command prompt available to the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilers can be used from command line (or makefiles) just like any other compilers. The main things you need to take care of are the INCLUDE and LIB environment variables, and PATH. If you're running from cmd.exe, you can just run this .bat to set the environment:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

follow these links for more information:
[Using Visual Studio's 'cl' from a normal command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84404/using-visual-studios-cl-from-a-normal-command-line)

[How to create a Batch File for Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879076/how-to-create-a-batch-file-for-visual-studio-command-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

If you put this line at the top of your bat file, it will set the environment variables for the visual studio command prompt

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

You may need to adjust for your version of VS and if you're on a 64bit machine.

Comment: Don't you need Call at the start of that line? Also, best to look at the properties of the shortcut to the existing Visual Studio command prompt. For example, my shortcuts have an parameter (eg x86)

Comment: @sgmoore it seems to work fine without `call`. And you're right, `%programfiles%` is probably better. But then if you're just running it on your machine it doesn't matter.